# Non-contiguous ranges for subtypes in Ada?

Tags: types, visibility, ada

Totally as an Ada-type-system learning exercise, I was trying to make 3 types (or rather, a type and 2 subtypes):

- `Month_Type`, an enumeration of all months
- `Short_Month_Type`, a `Month_Type` subtype only having the months with 30 days
- `February_Month_Type`, a subtype with just February

It seems that subtypes must use the `range` mechanism, correct? (Is there any other kind of subtype?) In order to get it to work with contiguous ranges, I had to put my `Month_Type` enumeration in this order:

```
   type Month_Type is (February, April, June, September, November, January, March, May, July, August, October, December);
```

Obviously this isn't the natural order of months, and I could see people/me trying to do `Month_Type'First` or something expecting to get January.

So, two general questions from this silly example:

1. Can I have a subtype that specifies specific components of its base type instead of a range?
2. Can I somehow hide the implementation detail of the order in which I put months (make 'First not visible, for example)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, an [enumeration](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-5-1.html) [subtype](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-2-2.html) only admits a [range_constraint](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-2-2.html) in this context, but you could create any number of [Sets](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-7.html) using [`Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-9.html). There are examples [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set#Ada) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jumbleada).

Comment: That is available, but its unneeded except in complex cases.

Comment: So, this is how I would have just approached things in other languages. What interested me was being able to use the type system itself to designate things like short months or odd numbers or whatever. But thank you for letting me know that this functionality is not always possible!

Answer (score 6):

You can make an *object* that designates only certain values in an enumeration. We would generally call this a "set".

A lot of languages have sets as basic types (along with arrays and records). Of course some don't. Ada is kind of in the middle. It doesn't *offically* have type named "set" or anything, but [boolean operations are defined to work like bitwise logical operations](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Basics&CID=210) on arrays of `boolean`. If you pack the array, you get pretty much exactly what other languages' "set" type give you. So **Ada does support sets**, they are just called "arrays of boolean".

```
type Month_Set is array (Month) of Boolean;
Short_Month : constant Month_Set := 
    (September => true, April => true, June => true, November => true, 
     February => true, others => false);
Y_Month : constant Month_Set :=
    (January => true, February => true, May => True, July => true, 
     others => false);

-- Inclusion
if (Short_Month(X)) then ...

-- Intersection (Short_Y will include only February)
Short_Y := Short_Month and Month_Ending_in_Y;

-- Union (Short_Y will include All Short_Months and all Y_Months
Short_Y := Short_Month or Month_Ending_in_Y;

-- Negation (Short_Y will include all Short_Months not ending in Y
Shorty_Y := Short_Month and not Month_Ending_in_Y;
```

Comment: +1 for an excellent alternative; see also [*4.5.1 Logical Operators and Short-circuit Control Forms*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-5-1.html).

Comment: This is a great answer, and something I didn't know about Ada. As I explained in another comment, I was interested in the type system itself being able to recognize a Short_Month from a Y_Month, hopefully at compile time. But obviously not everything one desires is possible :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [subtype predicates](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-2-5.html). In your case:

```
subtype Short_Month_Type is Month_Type with
  Static_Predicate => Short_Month_Type in April | June | September | November
```

Comment: It would probably be useful to mention that _subtype predicates_ were added in Ada 2012, and thus were not available at the time the origninal question was asked (by a few months)

Answer (score 2):

Trashgod answered the first question.
To answer the second question, make the type itself private.

Comment: Yes, that way one can expose as much, or as little, of the abstract data type as makes sense for the application.

Comment: I suppose I worded it poorly, but if I make the whole enumeration private, then no consumer of the package can really use it at all, right? I suppose I'd have to provide public Make_Month functions if I wanted them to be able to sling Februarys around, but not be allowed to do Month_Type'First?

Comment: Yes; another virtue of hiding the implementation in the abstract data type is that you can change it as needed, with clients none the wiser. For example, Java's [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) uses a packed boolean array internally for efficiency, as T.E.D. suggests.